# How to make a python package/distribution with files other than .py extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, software-distribution

[image: project structure]

I want to make a package/distribution of the project above, but the main module uses icon.png and saves files into the data folder. When launching setup.py with the following code

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Project',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['Main'],
      )
```

it makes a tar.gz archive only with main.py. How to include other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs on readthedocs.com](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html) you should add a file `MANIFEST.in` where you can include the files you wish to pack in your package.

```
include <project_name>/resources/icon.png
```

Another note from the page:

> In order for these files to be copied at install time to the package’s
>   folder inside site-packages, you’ll need to supply
>   include_package_data=True to the setup() function.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Also, you need to specify the full path, so I needed to add ```include <project_name>/resources/icon.png```